# MediaError is not defined

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

How to fix this error in chrome extension v3?

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    if (isPdfDownloadable(details)) {
      return undefined;
    }

    var viewerUrl = getViewerURL(details.url);

    return { redirectUrl: viewerUrl };
  },
  {
    urls: [
      "file://*/*.pdf",
      "file://*/*.PDF",
      ...// Duck-typing: MediaError.prototype.message was added in Chrome 59.
      (MediaError.prototype.hasOwnProperty("message")
        ? []
        : [
            // Note: Chrome 59 has disabled ftp resource loading by default:
            // https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5709390967472128
            "ftp://*/*.pdf",
            "ftp://*/*.PDF",
          ]),
    ],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"],
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Just tried to block, but not working. Who has any experiences to solve this?

Comment: Service workers don't have DOM and media stuff. You don't need this check because ManifestV3 means Chrome 88 or newer. Also, see the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/): ManifestV3 removed `blocking` mode from webRequest, you'll have to use declarativeNetRequest, although in your case it'll be probably impossible so your extension won't work in Chrome and Chromium-based browsers anymore.

Comment: This code was on v2 and works well. I am just convert this code to v3... another question. On v2, background page loaded the remote script from api.google.com, but how can implement this on v3? Do I have to save that file to local and load it? In this case, the problem is this remote script has another remote script. It shows CSP error. 
please help me.... :)

Comment: There's probably no solution. See if GAPI has a version for MV3.